# NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveURI], line 5 (Error code: -1001) with imacros

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, user-agent, imacros

I am using firefox 36 with latest imacros.

```
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !USERAGENT "Sony Experia z/10.0.011 (SymbianOS/9.4; U; Series60/5.0 Mozilla/5.0; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 ) AppleWebKit/525 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/525 3gpp-gba"
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=ACTION:/login/checkpoint/ ATTR=HREF:"*/captcha/tfbimage.php?captcha_challenge_code=*" CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
```

This is the error of this code.

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveURI], line 5 (Error code: -1001)
```

I have made it with imacros editor.On imacros browser it's working well.I am using a useragent in this code but it seems the problem is not for that.For this error I have searched in google and fined a solution in firefox developers forum.But I couldn't figure out of the process.By completing the process or if there is any other process somebody please help me to overcome the error.Thanks

It is the link of this forum page: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=815001
                                                https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=820522

Comment: This is due to e10s so dont downgrade just upgrade your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to downgrade of firefox for solving this error.This is error of imacros v8.8.0.If imacros is upgraded to v8.9.0 the error will be solved.

For upgrading Click here: [imcrosV8.9.0](http://download.imacros.net/addons/imacros-8.9.0.xpi)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue,
http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=19853&start=45
it is due to firefox latest updates.
Unfortunately, you have to downgrade to firefox 31 or 32.
Updates:
Works 100% with firefox 31

Comment: It's changing due to e10s so dont downgrade just upgrade your solution

Answer (score 1):

Try to update to the latest version 8.9.1.

2015-03-04 V8.9.1 => Download now (To install: Download, and then drag-and-drop the .xpi file onto an open instance of Firefox.).
Added Firefox 36 compatibility
**Fixes "NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments** [nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveURI]"
Fixes problem with JS code executed twice instead of once

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly the same problem firefox 36 with iMacros 8.8.x, this looks like the standard coding problem of an API parameter list changing (FF) and the client application (iMacros) failed to sync their client-calling code (until v. 8.9).  I am inclined to go with the recommendation of downgrading Firefox instead of upgrading iMacros, because:

- somebody mentioned that Firefox 36 is a bad version;
- I tested my code with FF 22 + iMacros 8.5 and FF 27 + iMacros 8.8, in both cases the problem went away;
- iMacros 8.9 (outside of the undocumented link above) is available via Softpedia, which I don't trust;
- my biggest reason: when I installed iMacros 8.9 for no apparent reason the web server apparently seems to think the browser is a mobile phone (I see "skin=mobile" added to the CGI parameters).

I couldn't find anything in the iMacro settings (FF plugin free version, that is) that sets the USERAGENT (or whatever) variable that is impersonating something mobile and it seems like an strange thing to do to default to something mobile, it should default to the browser (FF) at hand. I'll stick to Firefox 27.